# Reemplazo de eval javascript por soporte en internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript

Buen día chic@s, por soporte se debe trabajar en internet explorer 8. Revisando la versión de `ie8` tengo entendido que no es posible el trabajo con módulos por lo tanto el reemplazo de `eval` por alguna librería de las que he consultado al momento([eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eval), [static-eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-eval), [safe-eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-eval)) no se ha podido realizar(si saben de alguna sin import o exports muchas gracias).

Por ejemplo debugueando esta parte me he tocado con ejemplos como estos:

- `(9+6)*2` Debe procesar la operación

  - `eval("(9+6)*2")` implica que va a tomar el valor `30`, pues va a ser tomado de la siguiente forma `parseInt(eval("(9+6)*2"))`
- `01/12/2022` Debe procesar la fecha por lo tanto debería estar en la forma: `new Date("01/12/2022")`, sin embargo por el `eval` generamos un error(nuevos navegadores). `new Date(eval("01/12/2022"))`.

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- `0,12` debe procesar el Float. Lo mismo que para el int pero ahora con float `parseInt(eval("0,12"))`
- `id_data_input` Hace referencia al id de un input. Este ejemplo como toma solo el *String* lo he visto asi: `var dataId = eval("id_data_input");`

Y muchos otros.

En si uno de los problemas es que todos llegan a la misma función. por ejemplo

```js
function procesaTexto(valor, tipo){
  //logica para proceso con ifs anidados de la función principal
  if(tipo == "numero") {
    var dataNumero = parseInt(eval(valor))
    //... logica para este tio
  } else if(tipo == "float") {
    var dataFloat = parseFloat(eval(valor))
    //... logica para este tipo
  } else if(tipo == "fecha") {
    var dataFecha = new Date(eval(valor))
    //... logica para este tipo
  } //siguen los ifs
  // sigue la lógica y se utilizan las variables anteriores dependiendo 
  // del tipo de caso y van a ser asignadas nuevamente en otros valores
}
```

Al momento he tratado de eliminarlos utilizando la técnica de `return new Function`, sin embargo tengo el mismo problema. La otra es volver a rehacer estos `aspx` sin embargo no se como funcionan pues es algo de soporte únicamente lo cual me va a llevar mucho tiempo en entender todos los casos vistos y por procesar.

Talvez si saben de alguna forma de *interpretar* y poder solucionar.

> El cambio debe realizarse si o si pues es por advertencias de una herramienta de verificación y seguridad de código y debe poder ser utilizada en IE8

Comment: Cuál es el problema de Eval que lo quieres reemplazar??? Es una aplicación interna?

Comment: Son por temas de seguridad no puedes dejar abierto un `eval` te pueden inyectar codigo.

Comment: He investigado bastante el tema del Eval, en mi opinión su mala fama es sobre exagerada , en general el principal problema radica en la ejecución de código de terceros, por ejemplo parsear un JSON externo con Eval, donde era posible inyectar código malicioso para el cliente que lo ejecutaba. No obstante hay muchas otras maneras de inyección de script y temas de XSS. Es más, el motor de JS tiene el eval, por lo que una inyección puede usarlo sin tú lo hayas puesto en tu código.  Y preocuparse de la seguridad del Eval en IE8 es como preocuparse del paraguas antes den entrar a una piscina

Comment: En todo caso es mi  opinión a modo de concejo, tu evaluaras si la crees o no. Con respecto a tu pregunta, es demasiado general para responderla. Si das un caso particular se te puede ayudar a transformar esa función en algo que no ocupe Eval

Comment: Si en si el tema es por un XSS como te expongo en los casos eso es lo que se genera. El problema en si es que según la herramienta de verificación de código no se puede utilizar `eval` por lo tanto debo quitar los `eval` no tengo de otra.

Comment: Lo entiendo, yo he pasado por lo mismo. Una herramienta genera un reporte y dice "uuh un eval" lo marco como error gravísimo. Siendo que la herramienta no entiende el contexto de su uso, solo busca que exista el "eval". Porque `eval((9+6)*2)` tiene cero riesgo de seguridad. Yo te doy mi opinión porque sé que este tema es casi un mito, no busco un debate de ello. Aquí lo principal es que tu pregunta puede ser contestada, y así como está no lo es.

Comment: Por ejemplo partes pidiendo la recomendación de alguna librería, esto no es aceptado como pregunta. Luego pones ejemplo que yo no entiendo a qué van, deberías poner casos reales con código incluido. Por ejemplo: tengo una función que de entrada tiene X y salida Y, dentro hay un `eval` como lo reemplazo? Y por supuesto mostrando el código de la función, pero en una mínima expresión: leer [MRE]

Comment: Si lo entiendo es que igual se las librerías utilizadas todas usan `export` o `require` por lo tanto no puedo utilizar las mencionadas. Ahí agregue un poco de código de como funciona. Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución es tener un script para IE8 y otro para los otros navegadores más modernos. En estos últimos usas técnicas más actuales y para IE8 lo dejas tal cual, ya que digamos que dudo mucho que alguien que use IE8 esté preocupado por su seguridad, además que su uso es mínimo.

En los caso que muestras, hasta donde veo en algunos casos ni siquiera requiere el `eval` y en otros es necesario unos cambios menores

Ejemplo:

```js
function procesaTexto(valor, tipo){
  if(tipo == "numero") {
    return parseInt(valor); //sacamos el eval
   
  } else if(tipo == "float") {
      return parseFloat(valor.replace(",", ".")); //reemplazamos coma por punto

  } else if(tipo == "fecha") {
    return new Date(valor) //sacamos el eval
  }
  else if(tipo == "input") {
    return document.getElementById(valor); //usamos getElementById
  }
}

console.log(procesaTexto("23","numero"));
console.log(procesaTexto("0,12","float"));
console.log(procesaTexto("01/12/2022","fecha"));
console.log(procesaTexto("unaid","input"));
```

```html
<div id="unaid"></div>
```

---

El tema complejo es evaluar una expresión aritmética, tu mencionaste el uso de la clase "Function", veamos cómo queda:

```js
function procesaTexto(valor, tipo){
  if(tipo == "operacion") {
    return MathEval(valor)
   
  }
}
function MathEval(valor) {
   var func = new Function("return " + valor);
   return parseFloat(func());
}

console.log(procesaTexto("(9+6)*2","operacion"));
console.log(procesaTexto("1+2","operacion"));
```

Ahora debo decirte que esto no soluciona el fondo del problema, pero quizas el análisis de seguridad lo pase por alto. Es que usar `new Function` y `eval` es casi lo mismo, sobre todo en IE8, la diferencia principal radica en el ambito de las variables

Ejemplo de inyección:

```js
function ejecutar(){
 procesaTexto(entrada.value,"operacion")
}

function procesaTexto(valor, tipo){
  if(tipo == "operacion") {
    return MathEval(valor)
   
  }
}
function MathEval(valor) {
   var func = new Function("return " + valor);
   return parseFloat(func());
}
```

```html
<input id="entrada" value="alert('si entra')" />
<button onclick="ejecutar()" >Ejecutar</button>
```

**Pero es que incluso yo podría usar el eval dentro del `new Function!!!`:**

```js
function ejecutar(){
 procesaTexto(entrada.value,"operacion")
}

function procesaTexto(valor, tipo){
  if(tipo == "operacion") {
    return MathEval(valor)
   
  }
}
function MathEval(valor) {
   var func = new Function("return " + valor);
   return parseFloat(func());
}
```

```html
<input id="entrada" value="alert(eval('10+10'))" />
<button onclick="ejecutar()" >Ejecutar</button>
```

Y es que el tema de la inyección de script no pasa por el uso de `eval`, en mi opinión la mejor contra medida es la sanitización de variables, con especial precaución en datos precargados. Con sanitización me refiero, por ejemplo, en el caso de la expresión aritmética a solo aceptar números y símbolos matemáticos, no evitará del todo la inyección pero la dificulta enormemente.
Y sobre los datos precargados, por ejemplo cuando tienes una URL del tipo "www.algo.com/pagina.php?costo=2" y el sitio toma ese último`2` y pone como valor de un input, el cual hará uso de `eval`,  es regalarla inyección, cualquiera puede generar una URL con código malisioso, reemplazando el "2" por un script y enviarlo a otra persona para que lo ejecute.

Tampoco me quiero extender en esto, porque ni soy experto en seguridad ni la pregunta apuntaba a esto, pero seguramente el mejor opción para las expresiones matemáticas es buscar alguna librería solo de ello, que use arboles de expresión, pero creo que es matar una mosca con una bazuca.

Comment: Si ese es el principal problema. Solo se puede utilizar IE8(no se utilizan otros navegadores), por que toda la solución fue creada para el uso de IE8 solo con usar el IE9 ya lanza errores o bien no levanta bien. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La única solución que le veo al momento es re hacer los `aspx` :(

Comment: @DavElsanto Creo que no me entendiste, para todos los casos que tu pusiste existe una alternativa, excepto para la operación aritmética. Para este último caso puedes usar la solución que te di, yo agregaría alguna sanitización de todos modos, y con ello ver si pasa el test de vulnerabilidad, y si no pasas buscar una función que haga operación aritmética a partir de un string, que las hay y muchas